# Drop all rows that meet condition except the first one

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to drop all rows in a `pandas` dataframe that meet a certain condition except the first one. Note that the rows are not identical, so I cannot use `drop_duplicates()`.

For example, if I have the dataframe:

```
Type    Count
A           4
X          33
X           5
E          51
Y           7
```

and I want to filter on condition: `df[df.Type.isin(['X', 'Y'])]` would remove all rows where the type is `X` or `Y` resulting in:

```
Type    Count
A           4
E          51
```

but I want to keep the first occurrence that satisfies the condition such that the result is:

```
Type    Count
A           4
X          33
E          51
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the first value to `False` with `idxmax`:

```
m = df.Type.isin(['X', 'Y'])
m.loc[m.idxmax()] = False
df[~m]

  Type  Count
0    A      4
1    X     33
3    E     51
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

df['k']=np.where(df['Type'].isin(['X', 'Y']), 'x', np.arange(len(df)))

res=df.drop_duplicates(subset='k').drop('k', axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res

  Type Count
0    A     4
1    X    33
3    E    51
```